# IBM Db2 dsdriver environment variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

OS: RHEL 7.9
Build: ob_1_3_0

I have dsdriver and clidriver downloaded to `/opt/IBM`. I run `. ./db2cli` located in `/opt/IBM/dsdriver` to set environment variables so that `import ibm_db` works in python.

However, when running my python script externally (not from the CLI), the process fails because it cannot find `libdb2.so.1`.

Because setting environment variables in Python to rectify this seemed to have no effect (`os.environ["VAR"]="value"` and `os.system('source /opt/IBM/dsdriver/db2profile')` had no effect), I created symlinks to the libraries in `/usr/lib64`. However, the program ran into this problem later on:

`SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "3". SQLCODE=-1042`

Running `pip3 show ibm_db` yields the following:

```
Name: ibm-db
Version: 3.1.1
Summary: Python DBI driver for DB2 (LUW, zOS, i5) and IDS
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db/
Author: IBM Application Development Team
Author-email: opendev@us.ibm.com
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db-3.1.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg
Requires:
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get Python to have all the necessary variables set up so that the Db2 library works without issue.

Comment: Why do you have two separate drivers (dsdriver, and clidriver) ?  Only one is required (python ibm_db can use either of them, but only one should be installed/available to python, otherwise you get run time errors). When correctly configured, there is NO need to run ./db2cli to set environment variables for python ibm_db.  Please edit your question to detail your operating system, distro and version etc.

Comment: What environment? How did you install the ibm_db module? You don't need to download any driver package as part of a pip-based installation.

Comment: I was not sure which one to use. If I keep only dsdriver, what else needs to be done for python to see the library without telling it explicitly where to look? I've updated my post with my OS.

dsdriver was installed using installDSDriver, the ibm_db was installed using pip.

Answer (score 0):

Use dsdriver only when you need to

- compile (e.g. with C or C++ etc) code that directly uses the CLI API, or
- use jdbc/SQLJ, or
- you have code that depends on catalogued data sources, or
- when you want to use the db2 CLP, and other client side tooling.

For all simple use cases, use only clidriver, and *by default* the installation of the python ibm_db module will automatically download and install clidriver into the python site packages directory tree. When you allow automatic installation of clidriver, you can see the installation location with the command `pip show ibm_db` and examining the output for the directory location.

For simplest use cases, allow `pip install ibm_db` to install clidriver to the default location (under the site packages tree). For manual installation of any driver, prior to installing ibm_db, choose the most suitable location according to your needs, and then export IBM_DB_HOME to that location before installing ibm_db.

For example, if python will be used by a single user on the hostname, then you can install clidriver anywhere in `/home/$USER`, and of course if multiple users on the same hostname will run python then manually install the driver to a suitable location (e.g under `/opt` ) unless the driver has itself a default location (in which case use that default).

For RHEL and other Linux distros, to ensure that your user running python will be able load the Db2 shared library , you should arrange to edit your shell startup file (example .bashrc) to include:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/clidriver/lib:$LD_LIBRARY
```

where /path/to/clidriver/lib (or lib64 as appropriate) is the absolute path to the directory that contains the libdb2.so.1 file . When using dsdriver instead of clidriver, then the change is also required but this time the directory path must be the one of dsdriver lib/lib64 directory containing the libdb2.so.1 file. The relevant directory permissions and ownerships must also be compatible, i.e. must allow read and execute .

If you want python ibm_db to run for multiple users you can make this LD_LIBRARY_PATH change permanent (for all users) by editing /etc/ld.so.conf or creating a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d , or whatever method your distro provides for this purpose.

Comment: On [this page](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db/#description) it says:

Set this environment variable to avoid automatic downloading of the clidriver during installation. You could set this to the installation path of ODBC and CLI driver in your environment. The list of supported platforms and installation file names are listed in the table under License requirements.

Any idea where it places the clidriver files if you do not specify an IBM_DB_HOME value?